# Copy from Unix to Desktop without using any third party tool

Tags: unix

I want to copy my DBServer (LINUX) to Desktop . i can access the same from putty. but i dont want to use a third party  tool.
Is there any Command in Unix or linux to copy a file direct from Linux to Windows.

I want to copy a file from unix without using any third party tool. like winscp, Xftp

Comment: Yes, there's `cp` if you've got a shared mount.

Comment: Linux to Windows where? Two different computers? Virtual machines? On the same hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use ftp programs or software. A simple copy command

```
    cp filename1 destination/of/file2/filename2
```

and you are done. If you mean from a virtual machine or something that is a different story. In that case we need to know what setup you run.

Comment: Hi i was tryed belo command in linux 

sheel#cp scr.sql 172.17.189.181:c:\

Comment: Hi i was tryed belo command in linux     sheel# cp scr.sql 172.17.189.181:c:\   But the file is not comming to my c:\drive

Answer (score 0):

Share a windows folder and then mount it over the network using samba. If you have gnome, or KDE you will have a network bro

Comment: I don't have GUI access i want this to my desktop to a Linux Server . i did this using winscp but how to do this with third party tool. i used CP filename ipofDesktop:c:\sunil  but the file is not showing in the sunil shared folder.....